# Method to scale Hidden Markov model graph to overlay data?

Tags: r, matlab

I've been trying different implementations of HMM algorithms in R but one thing they all have in common is that they will only give absolute states in integers, i.e. 1, 2, 3...

There's a Matlab implementation of the Viterbi algorithm, called vbFRET that somehow autoscales the found states to the graph.

[image]

---

I've plotted data from both in R. Red line is the method used by the software vbFRET as above (I have some exported data, I didn't re-implement the method myself). Blue is my own fitting with the depmixS4 package in R, and scaled between 0 and 1.

[image]

How would I make a generalizable method to autoscale the integer states to the actual graph values?

Minimal example:
https://pastebin.com/78tqWc3Q

Code included, again, so the website won't be upset with me.

```
plot(E, type = "l")
lines(Single_Trace_state, lwd = 3, col = "blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

One method for the two-states case would be the following:

```
plot(E,type = "l")
means <- getpars(*your fitted depmix hmm*)[c(7,9)]
lines(1:length(E),means[*your fitted depmix hmm*@posterior$state],lwd=2,col=2)
```